# Looking for reference on general connections and covariant derivatives

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, smooth-manifolds, fiber-bundles, connections

I am teaching myself differential geometry  to be able to grasp General relativity.
I went through multiple textbook and have a fair amount on my bookshelf ( around 10-15 ).

Connections : 
I get disappointed most of the time when the topic of connections come up. All of my book (except for one see below ) introduce the principe of connection by listing the properties the one-form fulfill. I much prefer the angle of defining it by the distribution of Horizontal subspaces that makes more intuitive sense for me. Unfortunately  one one of my book treat this point of view namely : [Fibre bundle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387940871)
The later treatment of covariant derivatives doesn't suit me in this book as it is just a slapping of properties which I do not like ( basically because of the lack of history and intuition ).

Covariant derivatives :
The Covariant derivative and the exterior covariant derivative is pretty much the same story. I am quite not at ease when learning definition without much of history or what problem are we trying to solve by introducing such structures.

I would like to know a book or a reference that can fill the gaps in my knowledge/intuition.

- Def of a connection in terms of distribution of horizontal subspaces
- Derive the connection one-form from it
- Derive the Yang mills field by pulling back the one form on the base manifold
- Derive (somehow) the exterior covariant derivative
- Derive the concept of covariant derivative.

To sum up, I would like to get a rigorous treatment of these principles that will build my intuition better than just learning a bunch of properties.

Thanks for any suggestions !

Comment: I recommend Jeffrey Lee's text, for example: https://www.amazon.com/Manifolds-Differential-Geometry-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0821848151

Comment: Although, I suspect, https://www.amazon.com/Principal-Bundles-Classical-Case-Universitext/dp/3319147641 might be very much what you're looking for... I just got it a few months back, I haven't read much of it. Lee's book has helped me in various lectures at various times.

Comment: Thanks I will check out your references.

Comment: You might be interested in Nakahara's *Geometry, Topology and Physics*.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Turned out I had already went through Principal Bundle, the classical case. It has helped me a great deal learning connection but unfortunately build 0 intuition (for me) on the exterior covariant derivative, where the formula is just displayed as a definition page 141. Regarding Lee book The approach is really confusing, The covariant derivative is just defined at the beginning of the chapter and there is no mention of Yang mills and how to construct the covariant derivative on associated vector bundles.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thanks I will check out your reference !

Comment: Ah, sorry Lee didn't work for your questions, perhaps take a look at Gauge Theory and Variational Principles (Dover Books on Physics)  by Bleeker. I also second the recommendation of Nakahara. My friends in theoretical physics all studied Bertlmann's Anomalies in Quantum Field Theory. If you're looking for more physics it might be useful.

Comment: Incidentally, I think the field strength on the base manifold arises from the pull-back of the curvature form on the bundle. The gauge potential on the other hand arises from the pull-back of the connection one-form. All of these things can be derived from the concept of localizing a global symmetry. The argument goes back to Weyl who proposed it in 1929 for electrodynamics. For example, see Ryder's QFT text, he traces through why the Lagrangian for a complex scalar field must be modifed when the symmetry becomes local... it's not rigorous, but it is beautiful.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook yes Nakahara look promising, I am going through it right npw as well as Foundation of differential geometry vol1. I will check out your further references, I am wondering how much those concept will be useful for General relativity ( as this is my goal to learn ) but I hate being left in the dark by concepts.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook regarding the pull back of the curvature form on the bundle, yes I am aware of the definition ( which doesn´t bother me since I know the definition of connection one form and pull back ) the problem comes when defining the curvature form which is defined in terms of the exterior covariant derivative of the connection one form. since right now I am stuck at The intuition behind the definition of the exterior covariant derivative. i mean all treatments I was exposed too develop the theory in multiples pages to arrive to a covariant derivative ( starting from the notion of horizontal

Comment: Distributions, but everytime for the exterior covariant derivative it is only a definition made out of thin air ( I assume there is an intuition behind such a definition )